# Microsoft Sync Framework Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using the Microsoft Sync Framework v2.1 in order to synchronize two databases i.e. from remote (ms sql server 2012) to local (ms sql server express 2008 R2). The tables are able to be created successfully on the local database, however the data is not being synchronized due to the following error:

**The current operation could not be completed because the database is not provisioned for sync or you not have permissions to the sync configuration tables.**

However, when synchronizing 2 local databases (using ms sql server express 2008 R2), the synchronization is successful.

Anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem might be?

Thanks.

**CODE**

**The following is the main form:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // create a connection to the SyncExpressDB database
            string clientConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ianConnection"].ConnectionString;

            // create a connection to the SyncDB server database
            string serverConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["arvixeConnection"].ConnectionString;

            Utilities.Synchronisation.Db.DBSynchroniser dbSync = new DBSynchroniser(clientConn, serverConn);
            dbSync.ProvisionSyncScope("TestScope", "Products", DBSyncSide.Both);
            dbSync.Sync(Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncDirectionOrder.Download, "TestScope");
            label1.Text = "Sync Done !!!";
        }
    }
```

**The following is the synchronization class**

```
public class DBSynchroniser
    {
        SqlConnection clientConnection;
        SqlConnection serverConnection;

        SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator;

        private EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs> changeFailedHandler;
        public EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs> ChangeFailedHandler
        {
            get { return changeFailedHandler; }
            set { changeFailedHandler = value; }
        }

        public DBSynchroniser(string clientConn, string serverConn)
        {
            clientConnection = new SqlConnection(clientConn);
            serverConnection = new SqlConnection(serverConn);

            syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
            changeFailedHandler = new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(ApplyChangeFailed);
        }

        public void ProvisionSyncScope(string syncScopeName, string tableName, DBSyncSide syncSide)
        {
            ProvisionSyncScope(syncScopeName, new List<string>(new string[] { tableName }), syncSide);
        }


        public void ProvisionSyncScope(string syncScopeName, List<string> tableNames, DBSyncSide syncSide)
        {

            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc;
            // define a new scope
            scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(syncScopeName);
            scopeDesc.UserComment = "This is to test the sync class";

            foreach (string name in tableNames)
            {
                // get the description of the table name
                // and add the table description to the sync scope definition
                scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(name, serverConnection));
            }

            // create a server scope provisioning object based on the ProductScope
            SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConnection, scopeDesc);
            SqlSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConnection, scopeDesc);

            // skipping the creation of table since table already exists on server
            serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.CreateOrUseExisting);
            clientProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.CreateOrUseExisting);

            // start the provisioning process
            switch (syncSide)
            {
                case DBSyncSide.Client:
                    clientProvision.Apply();
                    break;
                case DBSyncSide.Server:
                    serverProvision.Apply();
                    break;
                case DBSyncSide.Both:
                    serverProvision.Apply();
                    clientProvision.Apply();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        public void DeprovisionScope(string scopeName, DBSyncSide syncSide)
        {
            SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning clientSqlDepro = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(clientConnection);
            SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning serverSqlDepro = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(serverConnection);

            // First save the deprovisioning script so it can be run on other SQL Server client databases.
            // This step is optional.
            //File.WriteAllText("SampleDeprovisionScript.txt", clientSqlDepro.ScriptDeprovisionScope(scopeName));

            // Remove the scope.
            switch (syncSide)
            {
                case DBSyncSide.Client:
                    clientSqlDepro.DeprovisionScope(scopeName);
                    break;
                case DBSyncSide.Server:
                    serverSqlDepro.DeprovisionScope(scopeName);
                    break;
                case DBSyncSide.Both:
                    clientSqlDepro.DeprovisionScope(scopeName);
                    serverSqlDepro.DeprovisionScope(scopeName);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        public DBSyncOperationStatistics Sync(SyncDirectionOrder direction, string syncScopeName)
        {
            // set local provider of orchestrator to a sync provider associated with the 
            // MySyncScope in the client database
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(syncScopeName, clientConnection); //check objectPrefix and schema

            // set the remote provider of orchestrator to a server sync provider associated with
            // the MySyncScope in the server database
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(syncScopeName, serverConnection); //check objectPrefix and schema

            // set the direction of sync session to Upload and Download
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = direction;

            // subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += changeFailedHandler;

            // execute the synchronization process
            DBSyncOperationStatistics syncStats = new DBSyncOperationStatistics(syncOrchestrator.Synchronize());

            //return statistics of synchronisation
            return syncStats;
        }



        private void ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw e.Error;
        }


        ~DBSynchroniser()
        {
            if (clientConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                clientConnection.Close();
                clientConnection.Dispose();
            }

            if (serverConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                serverConnection.Close();
                serverConnection.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you provisioning the database on the server? I normally do a PerformPostRestoreFixup after moving data to the server, then provision the database on the server.

Comment: are you using a non-dbo schema?

Comment: I am not an expert in database, however I think I am using a dbo schema, since at every table name, there is dbo in front of it (example: dbo.Users, dbo.Towns). Re PeterJ question, I think I am provisioning because all the required fields such as schema.info, tableName.tracking etc are created in both databases. However, I cannot transfer the data from the remote database to the local database. In the next comment, I will post the code using for synchronization

Comment: I have edited the post itself, I have added the code which I am using for synchronization. Can the problem be the ObjectPrefix and schema that are not specified? I did a comment in my code but I do not know what is ObjectPrefix

See the CODE section in my post. Thanks.

Comment: on the scope_info table, do you see your scope name in there? likewise, why are you provisioning everytime you sync? you should only provision a scope once.

Comment: Yes, I can see the scope name. On the other point, I have noticed that it is wrong to provision everytime since it will give you an error :) I have arranged that already. I have contacted my hosting to check the permissions since they are hosting the database but they said that the permissions are given by default. Does the problem relates to ObjectPrefix and schema? And if yes, the schema is the role used and what is the Object prefix please?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem. As I thought, it was a schema related problem. I specified the correct schemas since the schema on the remote database is different from the local one, and the problem is solved. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: could you share me the code as i want sync framework to work but do not know how to do

Answer (score 0):

I had a same Problem
As Dear user3206587 mentioned

**Client** and the **server** schemas must be simmilar for example both of them should be **dbo**.

Because if table prefixes become different we will be faced with provisioning or permission Error for instance

**dbo.tblTest**  is different with **sampleUser.tblTest**

you should change default schemas for sample user on server
exactly same as your local database.

Here I demonstrated how you can do the stuff:

[image: How to change sql server database default schema]